# Android - Image Drawable Animation with in fragment(Like Waze Report Screen)

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I need your help for Custom View with drawable Animation, animation will work at the time of fragment open. This fragment contains few images(Custom view with drawable). Like Waze Android App - Report Screen. Can anyone help me.

This image contains few images, it will animate when am open this fragment.
[image: This image contains few images, it will animate when am open this fragment.]